# What does outputting to /dev/null accomplish in bash scripts?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, redirect

Oftentimes I run into small bash scripts that use this sort of syntax in if statements:

```bash
some command > /dev/null 2>&1
```

What is the purpose of outputting to `/dev/null` like that, and what does the `2>&1` mean?

It always seems to work but I'd like to know what it's doing.

Comment: Not sure why this question was marked as a dupe, it was clearly open for 3 years before the other one was even posted.

Comment: I just noticed you were the OP and not a passer by. I've reviewed both Q&As and am voting to reopen your question. I think yours is more general and suits my needs tonight (getting rid of `650` or `3000` echoed to screen based on nighttime or daytime brightness levels. Whereas the other question is strictly about error messages (File Descriptor 2>/dev/null), One notorious example is `Gtk transient parent` in Zenity and Yad which use Dialog Windows instead of full windows. My initial comment was too hasty... PS w/formatting: `bash -c "echo $IntBrightness | sudo tee $backlight" > /dev/null`

Answer (score 209, accepted):

`>/dev/null` redirects the command standard output to the null device, which is a special device which discards the information written to it

`2>&1` redirects the standard error stream to the standard output stream (stderr = 2, stdout = 1). Note that this takes the standard error stream and points it to same location as standard output at that moment. This is the reason for the order `>/some/where 2>&1` because one needs to first point stdout to somewhere and *then* point stderr to the same location if one wants to combine both streams in the end.

In practice it prevents any output from the command (both stdout and stderr) from being displayed. It's used when you don't care about the command output.

Comment: And what does that `&` before 1 indicate in `2 >&1`

Comment: @Nobody "& indicates that what follows is a file descriptor and not a filename." https://stackoverflow.com/a/818284/5948237

Comment: @VivekChavda How come the 2 (stderr) doesn't need that distinction?

Comment: I was just copying from the answer I linked, I'm not familiar with all this myself. Here's a comment from under that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean/818284#comment32269807_818284

Comment: Those last 2 sentences ("**In practice it prevents any output from the command (both stdout and stderr) from being displayed. It's used when you don't care about the command output.**") should be bold. That's a pretty important piece of information just hanging out there at the end. I'd like it to stick out more.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. While I upvoted it, why do we have to provide the & for stdout and not simply say 2>1 instead of 2>&1

Answer (score 77):

STDIN is represented by 0, STDOUT by 1, and STDERR by 2.

**/dev/null** is the bit-bucket: the place where you dump anything you don't need.

---

So, the STDOUT is redirected to the bit-bucket(trash) and the STDERR is redirected to where the STDOUT is located: the bit-bucket.

---

You can also do this:

```
>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Nice explanation.  I also think there is a shortcut for the above:

    &> /dev/null

Comment: The shortcuts `&>` and `>&` are a bit frowned upon because those are "bashism" - they do work with `bash` shell but are not compatible with some other POSIX compatible shells. The `>... 2>&1 ...` syntax works in every POSIX compatible shell.