# Hide debug information when running apps from the command line

Tags: command-line, gedit

Most of the time running a `gtk` application from the command line it starts dumping debug information to the `stdout` even though I put them in background.

Example:

```
~$ gedit test.html # and ctrl+z to suspend
zsh: suspended  gedit .zshrc
~$ bg
[1]  + continued  gedit .zshrc
~$
# do some editing
(gedit:6208): GtkSourceView-WARNING **: Could not find word to remove in buffer (whoosh), this should not happen!

(gedit:6208): GtkSourceView-WARNING **: Could not find word to remove in buffer (haystack), this should not happen!
```

I want to note that the error, or warning, changes according to what I'm doing at the moment. The `GtkSourceView-WARNING` shown here is one of the cases.

Anyway... Do you know if it's at all possible to avoid getting that information printed out?

Comment: Is it a bug that this info creeps out to the `stdout` even though I'm `bg`ing the process?

Comment: I'm not acquainted with zsh, but I don't think so. Bash does the same thing.

Comment: I didn't meant a bug in zsh... I mean a general bug in any application to print debug information in `stdout` ....
Too much confusion in this question, I will vote for closing.

Comment: Don't close it; if you think it's too confusing, edit it so it's not. Personally, I think it's a great question, and in the question body, I only see one question anyway.

Comment: I would think piping it to grep with some arbitrary words after would work too.

i.e. `gedit | grep 'jkhcjbibijy1987189 jc1_12'`

Answer (score 8):

You can send those standard output and error messages [to the null device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12098/what-does-outputting-to-dev-null-accomplish-in-bash-scripts), so that they don't show up in your terminal, e.g. `gedit test.html >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: tutuca did in the first comment to his question.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do it would be to start the command as a background process and then detach it from the current shell. This will 'hide' all output in the sense that the current shell is no longer interested in the process. The syntax in bash is:

```
gedit test.html &
disown %1
```

I often use the output redirection mentioned in the other answer because it is very flexible. You can output to files, devices, connect outputs, etc. However this is useful for when you have no interest in the output, you just want to start a GUI application from a shell and then have no other interaction with it.

Comment: Why the parentheses?

Comment: That's more or less equivalent to what the questioneer is doing now, so no, that won't hide the output.

Comment: I believe this is the same as issuing `ctrl+z` and `bg`, right?

Comment: Yes it is the same but done without keyboard interaction so it can be used shell scripts and the like. Parentheses are for neatness.

Comment: This will simply send to the background, it won't affect the messages printed in any way.

Comment: @terdon - Addressed concerns and fixed answer so it detaches the process from the shell, thus there is no output to the shell.

Comment: @qeirha - See above

Comment: @tutuca - See above

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for and if it'll help you, but:

Since you're saying that you want to run a **GTK** application in the background, you could do this:

`nohup <applicationname> > /dev/null < /dev/null &`

The [nohup](http://ss64.com/bash/nohup.html) programm basically detaches the application passed to it from your terminal, allowing the terminal session to end, but with the application can still running.

You can close the terminal, or continue to use it (since all output is sent to /dev/null) without issues, because of the `&` command. A nice simple explanation for it can be seen [here](http://hacktux.com/bash/ampersand).

Comment: I know how to send apps to the background. What I want to avoid is the debug information getting printed. 
It happens with a lot of applications.

Comment: Did you try the command? Because `> /dev/null < /dev/null does what you want (or at least, for me it does)

Comment: What's the point of `< /dev/null`? `nohup` already combines stderr and stdout so `> /dev/null` will silence all warnings. `</dev/null` _reads_ from `/dev/null` and there's not point to that as far as I can tell.