# What does 2>/dev/null mean?

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect, stdout

I would like a brief explanation of the following command line:

```
grep -i 'abc' content 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 570, accepted):

The `>` operator redirects the output usually to a file but it can be to a device.  You can also use `>>` to append.

If you don't specify a number then the standard output stream is assumed, but you can also redirect errors:

`> file` redirects stdout to file
`1> file` redirects stdout to file

`2> file` redirects stderr to file

`&> file` redirects stdout and stderr to file
`> file 2>&1` redirects stdout and stderr to file

`/dev/null` is the null device it takes any input you want and throws it away. It can be used to suppress any output.

Note that `> file 2>&1` is an older syntax which still works, `&> file` is neater, but would not have worked on older systems.

Comment: is there a difference between `> /dev/null 2>&1` and `&> /dev/null`

Comment: In practice today I don't think there is `2>&1` is an older syntax  so `&>` would not have worked years ago but both are equivalent.

Comment: `foobar 2&1> file` does not work. It will send the `foobar 2` command to background and then run the command `1`, which will fail, it will also not redirect any output. You want `foobar > /dev/null 2&>1` or the shorter (and imo clearer): `foobar &> /dev/null`.

Comment: `&>` appears to work in `bash` and `zsh` but not `sh`, `csh`, or `ksh`. (I know, I know, this is AU, not U&L, and this info is probably of little value.)

Answer (score 49):

In short, it redirects `stderr` (`fd` 2) to the black hole (discards the output of the command).

Some commonly used pattern for redirection:

```
command > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Run `command` in the background, discard `stdout` and `stderr`

```
command >> /path/to/log 2>&1 &
```

Run `command`, append `stdout` and `stderr` to a log file.

In Bash 4+, a shorter (but less readable) form is functional

```
command &>> /path/to/log
```

Comment: Is there a good reason to use `> /dev/null 2>&1` instead of `&> /dev/null`?

Comment: @CraigMcQueen `&>` is new in Bash 4, the former is just the traditional way, I am just so used to it (easy to remember).

Comment: @CraigMcQueen according to a comment on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/12110/638128),  `&> /dev/null` may not work in some shells but > /dev/null 2>&1 will work in all POSIX compatible shells.

Comment: Why is it 2>&1 and not 2&1> ??

Comment: @marienbad that's actually a question worth posting :-) The syntax is `fn>target`, where `fn` is a file number (0-2 typically, some programs define more numbers) and `target` is usually a file name but here it is another filenumber - prefixed with `&` which is the syntax for "I want a filenumber instead of a file name".

Answer (score 21):

`/dev/null` is treated as black hole in Linux/Unix, so you can put anything into this but you will not be able to get it back from `/dev/null`.

Further, `2>` means that you are redirecting (i.e. `>`) the stderr (i.e. `2`) into the black hole (i.e. `/dev/null`)

Your command is:

```
grep -i 'abc' content 2>/dev/null
```

Don't try to end with another forward slash like this - `2>/dev/null/` (it's not a directory).

Answer (score 12):

grep -i 'abc' content will generate output which is displayed on your console, including any errors.

Specifying `2>/dev/null` will filter out the errors so that they will not be output to your console.

In more detail:
2 represents the error descriptor, which is where errors are written to. By default they are printed out on the console.

`\>` redirects output to the specified place, in this case `/dev/null`

`/dev/null` is the standard Linux device where you send output that you want ignored.

Comment: Concise and on-topic. Good answer.

Answer (score 5):

First we need to talk about `>` operator. It redirect the output of left of symbol to right of symbol.

So it must thought as :

> source_command > target_file

Other things that we must know

```
0 means stdin 
1 means stdout(useful output)
2 means stderr(error message output)
```

As **default**, it works as `command 1 > target_file`

As to `/dev/null` --> it is a special file that discards channel output redirect to it.

So in your question it means

> Run the command and **do not show me the error messages**, *discard them*.

Comment: It was very useful to have the meanings of different descriptors to get some more context and saved me an additional Google search.