# send logs to nowhere

Tags: command-line, logs

I run jupyter notebook (Python editor) on background in order to keep one terminal for keep working without needs to run a second terminal. so I have done this:

```
#jupyter notebook &
```

but the problem is when jupyter notebook is running it keeps send me logs, and this is typically painful and bother me when I'm typing command.

I wanted to stop jupyter notebook to send me these logs???

Comment: Also see: [What does 2>/dev/null mean?](https://askubuntu.com/q/350208/507051)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `&>/dev/null` to the command to send stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`, the nirvana of Linux systems:

```
jupyter notebook &>/dev/null &
```

By the way it doesn't matter where you put the redirection, that's also fine:

```
&>/dev/null jupyter notebook &
```

Comment: could you explain what the `&>` does in this case

Comment: @YassineSihi `&` takes stdout and stderr, `>` redirects it to somewhere, `/dev/null` is the null device. Also see here: https://askubuntu.com/a/350216/507051