# Stop output messages from cvlc

Tags: vlc, ubuntu-mate

```
cvlc --play-and-exit /usr/share/sounds/My_Sounds/Alarm-sound-buzzer.mp3 2> /dev/null
```

When I use this, I get these irritating messages like

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 19661 [30%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 19661 [30%] [on]
```

Any to suppress them?

Comment: Does this happen with normal typical audio files?

Comment: @doug Yes. With mp3 files. I am using Ubuntu Mate 18.04. It never occurred with 16.04.

Comment: If you were to run the same commands but  using vlc instead do you see the same? If so what does just plain vlc produce in terminal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does 2>/dev/null mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350208/what-does-2-dev-null-mean)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of just redirecting stderr with `2>`, replace it with  `2>&1` to redirect both stdin and stderr to `/dev/null`

```
cvlc -q --play-and-exit /usr/share/sounds/My_Sounds/Alarm-sound-buzzer.mp3 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: It did not help.

Comment: @fixit7 try adding the `-q` flag as shown

Comment: -q did not help. Did you try this out?

Comment: @fixit7 It seems to work for me even without the `-q` flag

Answer (score 0):

This can be made to work by redirecting all output (error and normal output) to `/dev/null`

```sh
cvlc --play-and-exit /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/bell.oga  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Don't you mean `... >/dev/null 2>&1` (mind the first `>`)?

Comment: This works. cvlc --play-and-exit /usr/share/sounds/My_Sounds/Alarm-sound-buzzer.mp3 > /dev/null 2>&1