# How can I redirect sox messages to null or a log file

Tags: redirect, sox

I run the following command to capture the output of audio into a file:

```
$ sox -t pulseaudio alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor -t mp3 test.mp3 silence 1 0.1 3% 1 3.0 3% > /dev/null

Input File     : 'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor' (pulseaudio)
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 16-bit
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM

In:0.00% 00:00:18.09 [00:00:00.00] Out:0     [      |      ]        Clip:0    ^C[C
```

As you see, while I tried to send the output to null, it stills show messages about the progress and status of recording!

I want it to record in background without showing these messages so that I can have the terminal prompts....

I checked `sox` for a log file but didn't find

Comment: Redirect `STDERR`, too. Replace "`>`" with "`&>`". Read `man bash`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 2>/dev/null mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350208/what-does-2-dev-null-mean)

Comment: @user3140225 No, that solution doesn't work for this case, I found `-q` can silent it, and will post the answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sox` has `-q` option if you don't want to see the messages.

You also forgot to specify what you want to send to `/dev/null`. It must be `1` (`STDOUT`), `2` (`STDError`) or `&` or `1&2` meaning both. check [What does 2>/dev/null mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350208/what-does-2-dev-null-mean)

If you want to run the command in background add `&` at the end of command.

So it must be one of the followings:

```
sox -q -t pulseaudio alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor -t mp3 test.mp3 silence 1 0.1 3% 1 3.0 3%  &
```

OR:

```
sox -t pulseaudio alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor -t mp3 test.mp3 silence 1 0.1 3% 1 3.0 3% &>/dev/null &
```