# Command line only terminal split

Tags: command-line

I am currently running a program that ouputs parcer error information for each time step that is being run. The output goes into the terminal. I was wondering if there was any way to split a terminal in command line only ubuntu? Is there a command for this or any way to even do this?

Thanks

Comment: You mean you don't want the errors printed? ... add `2> /dev/null` after the command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 2>/dev/null mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350208/what-does-2-dev-null-mean)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: What do you mean with "terminal"? A terminal window on your graphical desktop? A (virtual) console, what you get with CTRL+ALT+F1 etc? A terminal connected to a serial port? How do you start the program that outputs error information? What do you mean with "split a terminal"? Do you want to see the output in one part of the screen while you work interactively in some other part? Maybe you can use a code block in your question to show how it should look like.

Answer (score 2):

These multiplexers help split the terminal window horizontally as well as vertically:

Tmux: is arguably one of the most used multiplexers out there. It is quite a reliable screen splitter that helps you split the Linux terminal window and adjust the window’s size. It is a keyboard-centric multiplexer. Which means all the function and customizations can be carried out right from the keyboard.

Install Tmux

```
 sudo apt install tmux
```

To run Tmux

```
 tmux new -s dev
```

Keyboard Shortcuts:

```
CTRL + B + % : Vertical Split.
CTRL + B + “ : Horizontal Split.
CTRL + B + O : Make other shell active.
CTRL + B + D : To Detach from tmux.
CTRL + B + ? : Help.
```

Screen: is a shell multiplexer. It is quite a reliable and capable shell multiplexer. You can split-screen both vertically and horizontally and detach and reattach the screen from the running session.

To install Screen

```
  sudo apt install screen
```

To Start Screen

```
  screen
```

Keyboard Shortcuts

```
CTRL + A + | : Vertical Split
CTRL + A + S : Horizontal Split
CTRL + A + TAB : To make other shell active
CTRL + A + D : Detach from screen
CTRL + A + ? : Help
```