# How can I redirect output of a command in one terminal to another terminal?

Tags: command-line

Output can be redirected to a text file with `>` followed by the destination text file. How can we redirect the output to another terminal window or tab?

`>` or `1>` redirects standard output, `2>` redirects error messages.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to a different terminal, determine the file descriptor of the terminal with the command tty:

```
~$ tty
/dev/pts/0
```

Then redirect error messages to that terminal as in

```
~$ echo Hello World! >/dev/pts/0
```

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350208/what-does-2-dev-null-mean) to learn more about redirection of different outputs.